# Can you control hdfs file size for a HortonWorks HDP 3.4.1 Managed Table?

Tags: hive, hdfs, hdp

Currently testing a cluster and when using the `"CREATE TABLE AS"` the resulting managed table ends up being one file ~ 1.2 GB while the base file the query is created from has many small files.  The SELECT portion runs fast, but then the result is 2 reducers running to create one file which takes 75% of the run time.

Additional testing:

1) If using `"CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS"` is used the query runs very fast and there is no merge files step involved.

2) Also, the merging doesn't appear to occur with version HDP 3.0.1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify minimum number of generated files from Hive insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55372028/specify-minimum-number-of-generated-files-from-hive-insert)

Comment: Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38475807/2700344 Also read this about using rand() in the distribute by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58509772/2700344

Answer (score 0):

You can change `set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>` to let hive decide number of reducers based on reducer input size (default value is set to 1 GB  or 1000000000 bytes ) [ you can refer to links provided by @leftjoin to get more details about this property and fine tuning for your needs ]

Another option you can try is to change following properties

```
set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
```